# How to find absolute X, Y and Z coordinates in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have been working on Flash AS3 project. I am designing a 3D system.

Consider a MovieClip A which is at (0,0,0).
A contains B which is at (10,10,10). If I rotate A by 10 degrees then the position of B with respect to A remains the same but position of B with respect to the system changes.

To find Global X and Y of B, we have the function localToGlobal but it does not tell anything about the Z property. How to find that?

Please help! Thanks for considering this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out!

We can use myMovieClip.transform.getRelativeMatrix3d(root).position

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Transform.html

Thanks for all your help! This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the **local3DToGlobal** method. It uses all three coordinates from the Vector3D.

**local3DToGlobal** reference:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal3D()

**Vector3D** reference:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Vector3D.html

Comment: Thanks a lot!! but It converts the Vector3D object to a two dimensional Point. I am concerned about Z coordinate. I want something like local3DToGlobal3D which is not available.

Comment: It seems to return Vector3D meaning it returns the x, y, z. But the input parameter seems to only allow x and y. I'll see if I can find something that takes Vector3D and returns Vector3D

Comment: One solution would be to find the z value yourself, for example, how different is the z axis from the global? I think you should just consider a solution from that.